# Rename all .pdf files in subdirectories

Tags: terminal, rename

I have some directory containing several subdirectories. Each subdirectory contains one **.pdf** file with some random name. I want to rename all these files with `my_new_name.pdf`. What is the best way to do it using command prompt?